# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'torch.device' and 'int'

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, torch

```
2023-01-25 08:21:21,659 - ERROR - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/queue_handler/document_queue_listner.py", line 148, in __process_and_acknowledge
    pipeline_result = self.__process_document_type(message, pipeline_input)
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/queue_handler/document_queue_listner.py", line 194, in __process_document_type
    pipeline_result = bill_parser_pipeline.process(pipeline_input)
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/main/billparser/__init__.py", line 18, in process
    bill_extractor_model = MachineGeneratedBillExtractorModel()
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/main/billparser/models/qa_model.py", line 25, in __new__
    cls.__model = TransformersReader(model_name_or_path=cls.__model_path, use_gpu=False)
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/haystack/nodes/base.py", line 48, in wrapper_exportable_to_yaml
    init_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/haystack/nodes/reader/transformers.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.model = pipeline(
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py", line 542, in pipeline
    return task_class(model=model, framework=framework, task=task, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/question_answering.py", line 125, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/xyzUser/project/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 691, in __init__
    self.device = device if framework == "tf" else torch.device("cpu" if device < 0 else f"cuda:{device}")
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'torch.device' and 'int'
```

This is the error message i got after installing a requirement.txt file from my project. I think it is related to torch but also dont know how to fix it. I am new to hugging face transformers and dont know if it is a version issue.

Comment: Normally I would suggest filing an issue at the package's [issue tracker](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues) would get a quicker response, but given that I was able to trivially use git blame and find the specific issue has been corrected for you from their source repo, maybe if you can `pip install -U transformers` in your environment and see if that might fix your issue.

Comment: Updating did work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug with the [`transformers`](https://pypi.org/project/transformers/) package for a number of versions prior to `v4.22.0`, given that particular line of code does not discern between the type of the `device` argument could be a `torch.device` before comparing that with an `int`.  Tracing through `git blame`, we can find that [this specific change](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/commit/9d4a45509ab352c5a3e1113283cbae607133c0e8#diff-441f558737166b045444da9c4be81f566b3d69054e8f20e288aed746a691fa61L764-R773) made in changeset [`9d4a45509ab`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/commit/9d4a45509ab352c5a3e1113283cbae607133c0e8) include the much needed `if isinstance(device, torch.device):` provided by line 764 in the resulting file, which will ensure this error won't happen.  Checking the tags above will show that the release for `v4.22.0` and after should include this particular fix.  As a refresher, to update a specific package, activate the environment, and issue the following:

```
pip install -U transformers
```

Alternatively with a specific version, e.g.:

```
pip install -U transformers==4.22.0
```